# @Html.DropDownListFor is not picking up the default value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 5 values (code 1,2,3,4,5) in the model and assign the code 5 as default. It is picking up the 1st value which is 1. I used `Model.Eobadlstatus.Select(n => n.Code = 5)`

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EbAdlAmbulationCd, 
                          new SelectList(Model.Eobadlstatus, 
                                         "Code", 
                                         "Description", 
                                         Model.EbAdlAmbulationCd),
                          Model.Eobadlstatus.Select(n => n.Code = 5) )
```

Comment: Is "Model.Eobadlstatus.Select(n => n.Code = 5)" the way it is in your code?  Should it not be "Model.Eobadlstatus.Select(n => n.Code == 5)"?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is not the default value -- it's either an HTML attributes hash, or the option label.

- #1: `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression`
- #2: `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList`
- #3: `string optionLabel` -- OR -- `Object htmlAttributes`

The selected value is determined by the value of the model property, ie, `EbAdlAmbulationCd`.  If you want a default value, it's probably best to implement that in the model (data annotation, or in the model constructor, etc).